# Deep Link Configuration Issue in Expo: App Links Work via ADB Shell but Not on Device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking, eas

I hope someone has seen and solved this problem before.
I have a problem with deep links in expo. I am sure I have correctly configured and hosted the applinks file.
Deep links open with this adb command
`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://app.example.com" com.example.app`

but not this command
`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://app.example.com" com.example.app`

Consequently, links opened on the device itself, whether browser or through other apps does not open up my application. I have used `adb shell pm get-app-links com.example.app` to confirm the hosted asselinks file is verified.

These intents are in the app Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.example.app"/>
        <data android:scheme="exp+example-app"/>
        <data android:scheme="fb12****18050****3"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" data-generated="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="app.example.com"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     </intent-filter>
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: An update in case anyone spots this. I added http scheme to the manifest and the app launches. It seems there is a https conflict somewhere.

Comment: I finally figured it out. It seems having multiple intent filters with https causes issues. I presume specifically because it did not have a path or a host, so it automatically matched any https link.

I wrote a config plugin to remove https link from any intent filter that does not have AutoVerify true which is required for android deep links or web links.

I added my code here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19745#issuecomment-1778112276